# python tkinter, more than one item per row

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm quite new to python and tkinter so try to keep the answers simple please!

I've got the hang of setting up the window and adding in buttons, labels and photos etc, but I've noticed that whenever I use .pack() it just adds it to the middle of the window underneath the last thing I packed.

I was wondering if there is a way to pack the items in the same row as the last item I packed.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to take a look at *layouts*, e.g. http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_layout_management.php

Answer (score 1):

`pack` has options that let you control which side of the containing widget to use, the padding, and other things. For example, to pack widgets from left to right you would use `widget.pack(side='left')`. All of these options are well documented in many places.

Here's a quick example showing a row of buttons across the top, and a column of labels on the right:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.toolbar = tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
        self.labels = tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
        self.text = tk.Text(self, width=80, height=20)

        self.toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.labels.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        for i in range(5):
            button = tk.Button(self.toolbar, text="Button %d" %i)
            button.pack(side="left")


        for i in range(5):
            label = tk.Label(self.labels, text="Label %d" %i)
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=8)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

A nice tutorial of pack, including a list of all of the options, is here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm

A complete description of how the pack algorithm works is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M26